# Nullable variable is checked for null in method but not recognized

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

I am using IntelliJ IDEA's code inspection to evaluate the `@Nullable` annotations. At the moment I am using the `org.jetbrains.annotations` package, however I could also switch to another implementation if that helps with the problem.

The problem is that the nullity check of an annotated variable is done in another method. This is not recognized by the code inspector.

```java
@Nullable
private Bar myVar;

public boolean isNotNull() {
    // This check is actually more complex, but will
    // only ever return true if myVar is not null
    return myVar != null;
}

public void foo() {
    if (isNotNull()) {
        // Here I get a warning that myVar might be null
        myVar.bar();
    }
}
```

Can I somehow make IntelliJ recognize this condition?

Comment: Note that technically speaking, another thread may have set the value of `myVar` to `null` after `isNotNull()` has returned `true`, and before the call to `myVar.bar()` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that intellij is complaining because it doesn't know that the return value of `isNotNull()` indicates the nullity of `myVar`.

However, it could be null at that point you invoke `bar()`.

Some other thread could sneak in and change `myVar` back to null in between invoking `isNotNull()` and using `myVar`.

The only way to guarantee it is to:

1. Copy `myVar` into a local variable;
2. Use `localMyVar != null` and `localMyVar.bar()`.

Comment: Ok, and if I would not copy the variable locally, but instead use the global variable with a `mvVar != null` check, wouldn't that cause the same issue?

Comment: Yes. Because something could change `myVar` in between the `myVar != null` and `myVar.bar()`.

Comment: Yet IntelliJ does not warn me in such a case

Answer (score 1):

If your program is **single-threaded**, you shouldn't have to rewrite your program to satisfy IntelliJ's checks.
An alternate tool that can verify your code is the [Nullness Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker).
You [can run it within IntelliJ](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#intellij).

Here is a MWE.  The [`@EnsuresNonNullIf`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/EnsuresNonNullIf.html) annotation expresses your specification "This check ... will only ever return true if myVar is not null."

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.EnsuresNonNullIf;

public class SO57496219 {

  private @Nullable Object myVar;

  @EnsuresNonNullIf(result = true, expression = "myVar")
  public boolean isNotNull() {
    return myVar != null;
  }

  public void foo() {
    if (isNotNull()) {
      myVar.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

If your program is **multi-threaded**, you have several approaches.  Here are two of them.

- If the field is never reset to null by any thread, you can annotate the field as [`@MonotonicNonNull`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/MonotonicNonNull.html).  The Nullness Checker will verify that fact, not just trust it.
- You can pass the `-AconcurrentSemantics` command-line option.  This will verify only if you change your program, such as by putting the value in a local variable (as suggested by Andy Turner).  However, your program should probably use [locks](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#lock-checker) if you expect other threads to change the value concurrently.